# Android application to play videos at accelerated speed

Tags: android, video

I am looking for an Android application that can

- play videos at accelerated speed (e.g. x1.5 or x2)
- support at least some basic video codecs

(The VLC application is not compatible with my device, so in case it has this feature if not an option for me)

I use Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2 and Nexus 7 with Android 4.4.2.

Comment: What version of the Galaxy S3?  It's compatible with my i747 Galaxy S3 (which uses the Snapdragon SoC and is the model sold by AT&T.  The Verizon, Sprint, and T-Mobile versions also use this SoC) and I would think it should work on the Exynos-based models.  Have you tried using the apk [directly from videolan](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-android.html)?

Comment: @Compro01 Yep working now!

Comment: My new related question: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85183/android-app-for-playing-audio-files-at-high-speed

Answer (score 2):

[VLC](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videolan.vlc.betav7neon&hl=en) is now working on my device and fulfills my needs:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bit late, but [diceplayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inisoft.mediaplayer.a&hl=en) works nicely for this as well. You can also put it into a "windowed" mode which could be good for taking notes from lectures as you seemed to be doing.

It's not updated much, but still works well—even on the latest Android Marshmallow builds.