# Android app for playing audio files at high speed

Tags: android, audio, podcast, audio-player

I'm looking for an Android app (ideally free) with these features:

- resumes playing the file at the timestamp where I last was listening
- allows 0.25x-3x speed (and adjusts the pitch to sound normal even at different speeds) and remembers this setting
- allows easy transfer of audio file from PC (and ideally also from Mac and Linux) into the app (or allows playing files that I downloaded to certain folders on the phone via other means)

less important:

- has buttons for skipping 10 seconds forward or back
- skips silences (like the Podbean app does)

The app I've been using so far is VLC, but:

- it often moves the cursor back to the beginning of a track instead of resuming where it was playing last
- it doesn't remember my speed setting
- there is no easy way of importing files directly from PC (that I'm aware of)
- there are no ever-present buttons for skipping forward and back

Comment: VLC has all that but can only slow down to x0.25 (and at x0.25 with VLC, the voice may become choppy)

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @FranckDernoncourt. VLC is actually the app that I'm looking to replace. Please see my updated question. Thanks!

Comment: Have you looked at MPV for Android https://github.com/mpv-android/mpv-android ? I know that main version has speed control.

Comment: @ZZ Thanks, I'll check out https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=is.xyz.mpv

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for [Voice Audiobook Player](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/de.ph1b.audiobook/).

To be clear:

- resumes playing the file at the timestamp where I last was listening
- allows 0.5x-3.5x speed (and adjusts the pitch to sound normal even at different speeds) and remembers this setting for the Audiobook. (You can easily recompile it with e.G. 0.25x minimal speed)
- allows easy transfer of audio file from PC (and ideally also from Mac and Linux) into the app (or allows playing files that I downloaded to certain folders on the phone via other means) by just adding the specific folder(on your phone or SD card) to the library. (if you are searching for a tool to sync folders between devices i would recommend you a separate tool like syncthing).
- has buttons for skipping 20 seconds forward or back
- skips silences

Comment: Thanks, but neither that page nor https://github.com/PaulWoitaschek/Voice mention many features, so I'm not sure if it has the features in my list above.

Comment: Hmm sorry maybe my answere wasn't clear. 
I am using the app and as far as i understand your question it basically has all the features that you are asking for.

Comment: I just edited my answere to and referenced all every feature individually.

Comment: Thank you! I don't see Voice Audiobook Player or F-Droid in the Play store, and their website doesn't make it clear or easy to get started.

Comment: You should finde voice [hier in the google play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.ph1b.audiobook)

Comment: I personally would recommend you the [github](https://github.com/PaulWoitaschek/Voice/releases/latest) or the F-Droid (an open source play store) download as these build are from source without any additional trackers or stuff and they are the latest version. You can just need to download the .apk, provide permissions to install from the source (usually on the fly) and install the apk.

Comment: Hmm, the Play store says "This app is not available for any of your devices", which is probably why my Pixel 3 couldn't find it. I don't see an explanation for why it's not compatible with Pixel 3. Thanks.

Comment: hmmm that's strange... I am using the GitHub version so i cant say to much about it...